# How to use OnMouseEnter and onClick simultaneously on MUI Button or can we even do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, deployment, mern

I am working on a Login Button at header which not only shows the login dialog when clicked but show a dropdown onMouseEnter .
The Button used is an MUI component .
Here is the code for Button:-

```
                   <Button
                    onMouseEnter={handleClick}
                    onClick={() => { console.log("hi") }}
                    endIcon={ !Open ? <ArrowDownwardIcon/> : <ArrowUpwardIcon/>}
                    style={{ color: "#047BD5", background: "white" }} variant="contained">Login
                </Button>
                <Menu
                    id="basic-menu"
                    open={Open}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    onBlur={handleClose}
                    style={{width:"100%"}}
                    MenuListProps={{
                        'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
                    }}
                >
                    {Auth && <MenuItem style={{ color: "#047BD5" }} onClick={() => { setOpen(true)  }}>Login</MenuItem>}
                    <MenuItem style={{ color: "#047BD5" }}  onClick={() => { setSignOpen(true) }}>SignUp</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem style={{ color: "#047BD5" }} onClick={handleClose}>Orders</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem style={{ color: "#047BD5" }} onClick={handleClose}>Whislist</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem style={{ color: "#047BD5" }} onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
```

The lower menu part is Just the dropdown  .

**Problem**
When i move mousePointer to button to click , it does not accept the click event . Even the Hand pointer does not appear on Button . I understand the problem a bit but not as much to solve it .
**IN SHORT :- Only Hover event is getting triggered and not the onClick when Button is clicked .**
**Expectation**
I expecting that Hover event is triggerd when i move pointer to Button and when click on Button onClick Event should also get triggerd .I will be satisfied with js solution to instead of react or with simple Button instead of MUI Button .

It will surely make my day if you can help me it . If any others details are required please feel free to ask .
Thanks!
Have a error free day.